# Google Chrome: --headless --proxy-server

Tags: google-chrome, batch, proxy

I made a headless.bat file:

```
start /wait "" "%ProgramFiles%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" ^
--headless ^
--disable-gpu ^
--enable-logging ^
--proxy-server="http://ip:port" ^
--screenshot="%~dp0result.png" https://www.google.com
pause
```

So, if I **delete** `--proxy-server="http://ip:port" ^` line 
— this code makes a `result.png` screenshot of a (for example) `google.com` and places it right next to my batch, in the same folder.

**The problem is**: I don't like to access any sites without VPN (proxy). 
Therefore, I need that `--proxy-server` line; or something similar.

If I spare `--proxy-server` line 
— code also makes a `result.png` screenshot, but it's blank. 
And a `pause` in the end allows me to see **no errors** in the log.

I also tried `SOCKS5` instead of `http` with the same result. 
Both types of proxy IPs has been borrowed from free online lists.

What am I doing wrong?